# Chai-spies: AssertionError: expected { Spy }

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, chai

I am using chai-spies to make sure a function in my controller is invoked, here's my test:

```
it('Should show right season and analysts when competition has been selected', function (done) {
    scope.selectedCompetition = scope.competitions[3];
    var spy = chai.spy(scope.selectedCompetitionChanged);
    scope.selectedCompetitionChanged();
    expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
    done();
  });
```

where `scope.selectedCompetitionChanged` is a function. The test fails with the following error:

```
 AssertionError: expected { Spy } to have been called
        at Context.<anonymous> (base/tests/client/controllers/prediction.js?02f216981852d0775780926989e7266c6afb0af6:61:30)
```

How come this happen if I invoke explicitly call the function?
Thanks

Comment: I ended up using Sinon

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, I think you understood wrong [the docs](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies). With this:

```
var spy = chai.spy(scope.selectedCompetitionChanged);
```

You are just wrapping the function `scope.selectedCompetitionChanged` inside another function `spy`, so if you want to see the number of calls you have to use the new `spy()` instead of the original `scope.selectedCompetitionChanged()`.

Another way to track an object method is as follows:

```
var spy = chai.spy.on(scope, 'selectedCompetitionChanged');
```

Now you can call `scope.selectedCompetitionChanged()` as usual and it will count as a spy call.